# How do I build a global hashtable on parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, javascript-objects, parse-cloud-code

Im just getting started with Parse.com and Cloud code

Here is my challenge: I have about 4 classes on Parse.com

Now I'd like to maintain 2 global data structures that live alongside my Cloud Code

1. A hashtable of highest ranking data across all 4 classes
2. A queue of most recent data across all 4 classes

For 1, I think I have to write a background job that gets data across 4 classes and updates the hashtable. I want a hashtable with the hope that I can have a unique key across all 4 classes and values that point to only the relevant information from the 4 classes. Finally a client, may query for the entire list of hashtable keys, which it is also maintaining a local copy of, and then use those keys to fetch data that it has not seen before.

For 2, I think I have to write an afterSave cloud code to update the queue

Am I thinking this right so far?

Ok now how do I build this hashtable and queue ?

Comment: Firstly, Parse objectIds are unique across classes so you can use that. Second, why not just use the `updatedAt` column which is in every Parse class by default?  Finally, instead of a background job, why don't you use an `afterSave` trigger to update the highest rank?  The trigger can simply compare the rank of the updated item against the current highest ranks

Comment: Hi again @Paulw11! updatedAt sounds like a reasonable idea for most recent posts. however for highest ranking across multiple classes, i might need something more elaborate, since the requirement is something like top x% of highest ranking across multiple classes, and to do that for each query might be a bit much? especially if classes were to increase?